# INSTALL MULTIPLE VERSIONS OF SOFTWARE FOR DIFFERENT ACCOUNTS

Tags: versions, multiple-users

Good Morning,

I am wondering if there is a possibility in Ubuntu to have different users with different softwares versions.

The problem is, even if I am able to install the different versions in the different users' home folders, nevertheless I don't know how to change the path for every user to point to the right installation.

thanks

Comment: Which software are you planning to install? The default Ubuntu repositories come with a single version of a software.

Comment: Depends upon the software. In general, Debian-based systems like Ubuntu are poor candidates for this kind of customization. One of the core Debian assumptions is that multiple versions on the same system is an UNdesirable situation, and is prohibited by apt.

Comment: You can multiboot multiple versions of Ubuntu on the same drive. Each version can have it's own software and it's own users and can also be it's own flavour. How many different users are involved?

Answer (score 2):

In general, Debian-based systems like Ubuntu are poor candidates for this kind of customization.

- One of the core Debian assumptions is that multiple versions on the same system is an undesirable situation.
- Consequently, apt works very hard to prohibit multiple versions on the same system.

So you're fighting against a bit of a tide here. Your use of apt's convenience (including dpkg and deb packages) is limited. But it's still definitely possible:

Option #1: Snaps. You can have as many different snap versions as you like. Every user has access to all versions.

Option #2: VM/Container: You can provide each user with their own container or VM, with their own preferred environment inside. This has an advantage that each user sees ONLY their preferred versions.

Option #3: Manual install. You can have as many versions of software installed as you wish...as long as you install and administer them manually.

These options are not exclusive: Your container can have manually-installed software or snaps (or debs!) inside it.